# Xcode ios: Streaming of video file while recording

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avfoundation

Can anybody suggest how I can upload video file while recording.

As I am recording video using `AVFoundation` this will save video to some file eg. record.mov .

Now my query is how I can upload this video while recording, as I want to save user time as soon as user record his/her video should be uploaded.

Right now I am trying with HTTP, File stream to upload video.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and because it might help you get better answers, what will be done with the uploaded video data?

Comment: Share on Youtube or some other social web site...

Comment: It seems like a nice idea, but: streaming video from a device depends a lot on quality of a connection. Too many options to go wrong and if that interrupts the recording part (let's say a dialog pops up that a connection had been lost) your users won't be very happy. Here are some usefull links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258696/turning-an-iphone-or-ipod-into-a-wireless-webcam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution to capture videos frame while recording using AVFoundation

Apple provided this sample code

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @Kamleshawar Can you please share the sample code for this.

Comment: Sorry!!, Implemented for my client :( will try to implement with some same then I will share