# Live Streaming Video in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to `iPhone` Development. I need to capture video. While I'm capturing video it display on server too. Something like live streaming.

Anyone have idea from where I should have to start for this functionality?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems similar to this

[Xcode ios: Streaming of video file while recording and removed redundant personal statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390647/xcode-ios-streaming-of-video-file-while-recording)

**First Half Solution**

Using AVFoundation you can get video Buffer/frames while recording.

**Second Half**

But for uploading i didn't find any solution

There is Input Stream option there in iOS APIs but it need some file path. but as video is not recorded we didn't have any path.

**Edit 1**

Here is [Best Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) for AVFoundation provided by Apple, you can start with

Comment: I have done with First solution, but still working on second part to upload on server.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use wowza wowza.com/https://www.wowza.com, it has all the features, from live stream, video on demand and etc.