# Stream video from iPhone to web server - compress and stream step

Tags: iphone, video, camera, streaming, avfoundation

I have seen a few other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327159/stream-video-from-iphone) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258696/turning-an-iphone-or-ipod-into-a-wireless-webcam). The second link is precisely what I want to do, however I can't get past step 2 in the answer: Compress/Stream to server.

EDIT:

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062266/uploading-live-streaming-video-from-iphone/5601041#5601041) example working, but I need to know how to setup the server to receive the frames that I send. How do you receive a bunch of pictures and turn them into a video?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html. This sample uses an AVAssetWriter to encode the video from the camera to H264 and then uses RTSP/RTP to stream the data to a player.